# Invalid project contents directory error

Tags: php, eclipse

When I try to load my existing project using Eclipse I get the error of "Invalid project contents directory".

I have created those files in Windows environment and now I'm trying to open those files as PHP projects in Linux.

What can I do to fix this problem?

[image]

Comment: The problem is that eclipse does not have proper permissions to write to /var/www.  You can either chmod or open using sudo.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After using chown command on my www folder recursively, the problem was gone. I think the problem was that eclipse can't create new files inside those folders. (Duh!)

So:

```
sudo chown -R /var/www user:group
```

Answer (score 3):

There is another workaround: you can run the eclipse via terminal using sudo command.

Answer (score 1):

Use 
`sudo chown -R $USER:$USER /var/www` to allow access to the folder by its ordinary user

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that Eclipse cannot write its project files to the directory, as also addressed by the other answers.

If you don't want to change ownership of the files, there is an alternative way:
If the files are, e.g., owned by user `www-data` and group `www-data`, then you can become member of group `www-data`, and then give group write permission to everything in that directory tree:

```
sudo chmod -R g+w /var/www
```

This way, the webserver will still be able to access those files with its user `www-data`.