# Eclipse: How to import ZendSkeleton project into Eclipse with PDT plugin?

Tags: eclipse-plugin, zend-framework2, eclipse-pdt

How do you import an existing zendskeleton project into Eclipse with the PDT plugin? I have tried the following:

(1) Installed PDT
(2) File->New->other->PHP project
(3) Project from existing source

But I get this error "Invalid project contents directory".

Now I look to the wisdom of all you willing to help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer! Eclipse does not have the correct permissions so I :

(1) Opened terminal->su to have root -> then launched eclipse from the terminal with root.

You can also change permission on files follow these links:

[How do I set chmod for a folder and all of its subfolders and files in Linux Ubuntu Terminal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3740152/how-to-set-chmod-for-a-folder-and-all-of-its-subfolders-and-files-in-linux-ubunt)

[Invalid project contents directory error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17073608/invalid-project-contents-directory-error)